# Arco 2D en unity

Tags: c#, unity, unity2d, motor-de-juego

soy nuevo en unity y estoy teniendo problemas para hacer que un arco 2D rote. Lo que quiero hacer es que al mover un objeto invisible(objeto1) alrededor del arco(objeto2) el objeto2 rote sobre si mismo apuntando en dirección contraria hacia el objeto1 y así apuntar el arco a donde se desee. Igual que en el juego de android "Zombirds".

Lo máximo que he conseguido es que el objeto2 rote alrededor del centro de la pantalla y no sobre sí mismo y no entiendo el por qué.
Aquí dejo el script que maneja la rotación y un video corto que muestra el problema de rotación del arco.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Controlador : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform target;
    
    public float speed = 5.0f;

    void Update()
    {
         Vector2 direction = target.position - transform.position;
         float angle = Mathf.Atan2(direction.y, direction.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
         transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, 0f, angle);
         
    }
}
```

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lU0GB7QCm8BwKjt0j3UrCCYBKZLxb-bq/view?usp=drive_link

Comment: Puedes usar `transform.LookAt(posicion)` o `Quaternion.LookRotation` si necesitas un Quaternion en lugar de hacer tú los cálculos.

Comment: Ya he probado con
`void Update() {
    Vector3 direction = target.position - transform.position;
    direction.Normalize();
    float rotationZ = Mathf.Atan2(direction.y, direction.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, 0f, rotationZ);
}`

y

`void Update() {
    Vector3 direction = target.position - transform.position;
    direction.z = 0; 
    transform.LookAt(transform.position + direction);
}'

Llevo ya 3 días probando de todo y no consigo nada

Comment: Ese link es al proyecto? No me deja entrar. Luego lo miro.

Comment: Es un video grabado de como gira mal el arco, puedo pasarte el proyecto si quieres

Comment: Si puedes sí. ¿Target sería el objeto invisible?

Comment: El segundo código que escribiste no funciona porque `LookAt` no es relativo. Toma la posición absoluta del punto al que debe *mirar*. Internamente seguro haga la resta para obtener la dirección y llame a la función `Quaternion.LookRotation`.

Comment: Si, target es el objeto invisible, aunque le he asignado un cubo para poder verlo de momento. Ahora estoy fuera de casa, sobre las 8 30 te envio el proyecto y miro lo del quaternion.

Comment: Aquí lo tienes:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VpYz4mpRuxU8h4AD3GbxGLXE2crEIpsL/view?usp=drive_link

Comment: He probado con `Quaternion.LookRotation` y sigue sin funcionar, el arco rota alrededor del centro de la pantalla en vez de sobre sí mismo, no sé qué hacer ya.

Comment: Nada, ya lo he solucionado, el problema era que debido a que el arco y flecha estaban agrupados en otro objeto, no sé por qué pero este objeto tenia una "hitbox" muy larga, y por eso rotaba alrededor del centro de la pantalla, he tirado 8h de mi vida por esta tontería.